# React ClassName is not applying on the text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I started coding react these days. Today I've opened a new project and when I tried to apply a style className but it's showing the regular `<span>` without any style. This is my counter.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="badge badge-primary">Test</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Here's a Stack Snippet:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="badge badge-primary">Test</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.badge {
    font-style: italic;
}
.badge-primary {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Have you imported your CSS file?

Comment: What is the CSS that is being applied against this `span` element? Can you include your CSS in your question?

Comment: I've copied your code into a Stack Snippet. As you can see, it applies the class names to the `span`. Please edit the snippet to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Comment: @virtual I assume that you used create-react-app as boilerplate, in App.js you probably removed the import line of the css, or you put your style in the wrong css file, it should be in App.css

Answer (score 0):

Please import css file path in your react component file, just like:
import './styles.css';

Comment: Can you please give me a full example for the line of code?

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css'; //Please add path of wherever your css file is located.

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="badge badge-primary">Test</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;

Comment: my styles located in the src folder and i have only app.css and index.css

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your .css file where CSS class "badge badge-primary" is defined. You can import it in counter.jsx or in App.jsx. The syntax is

```
import 'path_to_style/css_file_name.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

Add `@import './src/your_file_path';` at the beginning of your **index.css**